# Fully connected layers with unflattened input

Tags: neural-network, linear-algebra, pytorch

```
(batch_size, 70, 2, 2) -> Linear(2, 2)

(batch_size, 140, 2) -> Linear(2, 2)

(batch_size, 280) -> Linear(280, 2)
```

Can someone explain to me how Fully Connected layers work with non-flattened input data? I don't really know how to think about > 2D matrix multiplication. Are all the above equivalent? (Linear is the fully connected module in pytorch)

Answer (score 0):

For multiplications that are done on tensors greater than rank-2 (matrix) the following condition needs to be satisfied, for example consider 2 tensors `A` and `B`

`A.shape=[a1,a2,a3...a8]` and `B.shape=[b1,b2,b3... b8]`

Although I dont know how matrix multiplication is done in pytorch I expect it to be similar to tensorflow.

if you do `tf.matmul` in tensorflow it would do matrix multiplication on the `(a7,a8)` and `(b7,b8)` this requires that `a8` be equal to `b7` for the operation `A.B`, additionally it also requires that `a1..a6` be equal to `b1..b6`

The output shape would be `[a1, a2...a7,b8]`

The above 3 are equivalent only in the sense that they are simply flattened on an axis